# VueCLI3 app (nginx/docker) use environment specific variables

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, environment-variables, vue-cli-3

How to *externalize* and *consume* environment variables from a Vue App:

- Created with [VueCLI3](https://cli.vuejs.org/)
- Deployed in a docker container
- Using NGINX

### Some details:

The project is **built once** and deployed to test and live environments. So, I want to externalize some variables which **change through the environments** (like URLs to call, domains, usernames etc.). The classical usage with `.env` file variations with `VUE_APP_` prefixed does not help this issue as their values are injected in the code during the build stage: They are not variables once it is built.

Trying it out, I have found a [blog post](https://www.georg-ledermann.de/blog/2018/04/27/dockerize-and-configure-javascript-single-page-application/) making use of `dotenv` and some extra configuration; but I could not put it together with the configuration in [this VueCLI 3 official guide](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#docker-nginx). The solution does not need to adopt a similar approach though, I am just trying to make a way out.

Probably not a useful information, but I am planning to define those environment variables in [Config Maps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables) in Kubernetes configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've accomplished to overcome this case. I am leaving the resolution here.

1. Define your environment-specific environment variables in `.env.development` (for development purposes) and add them also to the [Pod configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container) with correxponding values.
2. Add a `configuration.js` file somewhere in your Vue project source folder. It would act as a wrapper for determining whether the runtime is development (local) or production (container). It is like the one shown [here](https://www.georg-ledermann.de/blog/2018/04/27/dockerize-and-configure-javascript-single-page-application/), but importing/configuring `dotenv` is not required:

   ```js
   export default class Configuration {
     static get EnvConfig () {
       return {
         envKey1: '$ENV_KEY_1',
         envKey2: '$ENV_KEY_2'
       }
     }

     static value (key) {
       // If the key does not exist in the EnvConfig object of the class, return null
       if (!this.EnvConfig.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         console.error(`Configuration: There is no key named "${key}". Please add it in Configuration class.`)
         return
       }

       // Get the value
       const value = this.EnvConfig[key]

       // If the value is null, return
       if (!value) {
         console.error(`Configuration: Value for "${key}" is not defined`)
         return
       }

       if (!value.startsWith('$VUE_APP_')) {
         // value was already replaced, it seems we are in production (containerized).
         return value
       }

       // value was not replaced, it seems we are in development.
       const envName = value.substr(1) // Remove $ and get current value from process.env
       const envValue = process.env[envName]

       if (!envValue) {
         console.error(`Configuration: Environment variable "${envName}" is not defined`)
         return
       }

       return envValue
     }
   }
   ```
3. Create an `entrypoint.sh`. With some modification, it would look like follows:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash

   function join_by { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }

   # Find vue env vars
   vars=$(env | grep VUE_APP_ | awk -F = '{print "$"$1}')
   vars=$(join_by ',' $vars)
   echo "Found variables $vars"

   for file in /app/js/app.*;
   do
     echo "Processing $file ...";

     # Use the existing JS file as template
     cp $file $file.tmpl
     envsubst "$vars" < $file.tmpl > $file
     rm $file.tmpl
   done

   nginx -g 'daemon off;'
   ```
4. In your `Dockerfile`, add a `CMD` for running this `entrypoint.sh` script above **as a bootstrapping script during container creation**. So that, every time you start a container, it will get the environment variables from the pod configuration and inject it to the Configuration class shown in *Step 2*.

   ```
   # build stage
   FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage

   # make the 'app' folder the current working directory
   WORKDIR /app

   # Copy package*.json and install dependencies in a separaate step to enable caching
   COPY package*.json ./
   RUN npm install

   # copy project files and folders to the current working directory
   COPY ./ .

   # install dependencies and build app for production with minification
   RUN npm run build

   # Production stage
   FROM nginx as production-stage

   RUN mkdir /app

   # copy 'dist' content from the previous stage i.e. build
   COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app

   # copy nginx configuration
   COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

   # Copy the bootstrapping script to inject environment-specific values and pass it as argument current to entrypoint
   COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh

   # Make the file executable
   RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

   CMD ["./entrypoint.sh"]
   ```

Finally, instead of `process.env` use our wrapper configuration class like `Configuration.value('envKey1')`. And voila!